# configuration.module.rules[2] Issue in @electron-forge/plugin-webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, electron-forge

Here is some info about the machine I'm using:

- Node v14.17.0
- Electron v13.1.2
- Win 10 21H1
- Yarn 2.4.2

I'm trying to get my project here at: https://github.com/Cokaps/GenZOC working but I've ran to this issue:
**When I run electron-forge start, it shows an error here:**

```sh
PS D:\GenZOC> yarn start
✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies: 1 / 1
✔ Compiling Main Process Code
✖ Launch Dev Servers

An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, 
mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[2] should be "...".
    * configuration.module.rules[2] should be an object:
      object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
      -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.     
 - configuration.module.rules[2] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, 
mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[2] should be "...".
    * configuration.module.rules[2] should be an object:
      object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
      -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
    at validate (D:\GenZOC\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:104:11)
    at validateSchema (D:\GenZOC\node_modules\webpack\lib\validateSchema.js:78:2)
    at create (D:\GenZOC\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:109:24)
    at webpack (D:\GenZOC\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:151:32)
    at f (D:\GenZOC\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js:55:16)
    at D:\GenZOC\node_modules\@electron-forge\plugin-webpack\src\WebpackPlugin.ts:296:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

In my repo (link above), the config for electron forge is `/forge.config.js`, `/webpack.js` for main process and `/webpack.renderer.js` is for renderer.
Is there anyway to fix this. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Edit: When I change `rules.push` in webpack.renderer.js to comment, it work but I want to find a fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try loading like this in webpack.renderer.js:

```js
const nativeRules = require('./webpack.rules.js');
// ...
 module: {
        rules: [
            nativeRules,
           // other rules that you want to load
```

Comment: Well, I tried but doesn't help. Let me see.

Comment: It works now!!! It works by using like this in webpack.renderer.js:
```js
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.node$/,
                use: 'node-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
                parser: { amd: false },
                use: {
                    loader: '@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
                    options: {
                        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
                    },
                },
            },
// other things
```